# How to use Font Awesome icons in python plotly dash

Tags: python, html, font-awesome, plotly-dash

I want to display Font Awesome Icons in Dash but it doesn't seem to work.

I added the font-awesome stylesheet:

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css']
app = dash.Dash('SimpleDashboard',external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, external_stylesheets])
```

And added this to my page:

```
html.Div([
           html.I(className="fa fa-shield"),
    ])
```

But it displays nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked over here? https://community.plot.ly/t/anyone-got-font-awesome-fonts-displayable-within-dash/5960

Comment: @SSharma Yes and I tried the solution suggested there but the icon fails to show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you can do it directly from dash-bootstrap-components.
Here is the example from [official docs](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/icons/):

> dash-bootstrap-components contains CDN links for Bootstrap Icons v1.8.1 and Font Awesome v6.1.1, two libraries of icons you can use in your apps. You can use either of them by adding them to external_stylesheets when instantiating your app.

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# For Bootstrap Icons...
app = dash.Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]
)
# Or for Font Awesome Icons...
app = dash.Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, dbc.icons.FONT_AWESOME]
)
```

Comment: That's the current best answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have created a very simple dash component called DashIconify. You can use that to add icons in your dash app. https://github.com/snehilvj/dash-iconify

**Installation**

`pip install dash-iconify`

**Usage**

```py
from dash import Dash, html
from dash_iconify import DashIconify

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    DashIconify(
        icon="ion:logo-github",
        width=30,
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

You can search for the icon name here: https://icon-sets.iconify.design

Unlike existing solutions, where you have to include the complete set of icons in external_stylesheets, with this library, you can select icons from many different sets in one single app, as it won't download those sets entirely, just the icons that you specify.

To use font-awesome icons in your app, just do this:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    DashIconify(icon="fa-solid:shield-alt")
])
```

Comment: success w dash 2.5.1 in 2022. the icons ultimately appear as text and respond to css just like unicode

Answer (score 3):

Try this for external stylesheets:

```
external_stylesheets = [
{
    'href': 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css',
    'rel': 'stylesheet',
    'integrity': 'sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf',
    'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
}
]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, unfortuantely this does not work. The icon still does not show up

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your external_stylesheets variable as a list, but it should just be a string. The dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=list) argument takes a list - in your case that should be [bootstrap, font-awesome] - but you are giving it a list[str, list], namely: [bootstrap, [font-awesome]]. Pass it a list of external stylesheets and it should work!

```
external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP,
                        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
                       ]
app = dash.Dash('SimpleDashboard',external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the version of font-awesome contains the icon you're referencing + the font-awesome class prefix combatibility.

In the case of `4.7.0` you should use the following reference:

```
html.Div([
           html.I(className="fas fa-shield"),
    ])
```

If you're using `5.8.1`, use the following:

```
html.Div([
           html.I(className="fas fa-shield-alt"),
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout for external_stylesheets: Seems to work on my end.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

external_stylesheets = [
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
     dbc.themes.SLATE
]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div([
           html.I(className="fa fa-shield"),
    ]),

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

[AUBSieGUL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8832072/aubsiegul)

Your code should look something like this:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

Instead of

```
app = dash.Dash('SimpleDashboard',external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, external_stylesheets])
```

Just replace 'SimpleDashboard' with `__name__`

[Here is why](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-app-does-not-load-assets-and-app-index-string/12178/10?u=chriddyp) it should be this way

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to append different stylesheets to the app and got it working with this (exclude dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP,'./assets/mycss.css' to get it running, I added them here only to show how to add different types):

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
for css in [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP,
            './assets/mycss.css',
            'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css']:
   app.css.append_css({"external_url": css})
```

in the layout its:

```
dbc.Button(children=[html.I(className="fas fa-plus-square")])
```

perhaps also check beforehand if the icon you want is listed here
https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css